# JQuery/AJAX update DIV from MYSQL - Get values from different input 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a bit new to JQuery and I have a script that will get the values from a text input on an onchange event and will send the data to an external PHP file so we can get some data from the DB in fetch it into a DIV with id "txtHint3".

The whole script works perfectly fine but the problem I have is I need to get the values from 2 different text input fields and send the 2 values to the PHP file.

Essentially if only 1 of the 2 input text changes, we need to push back the 2 values to jQuery and the to PHP script.

I have tried a few different ways without any significant result. Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is the jQuery code I wrote so far :

```
<script>
    function recordTrans(str) {
if (str == "") {`enter code here`
    document.getElementById("txtHint3").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint3").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","recordtransaction.php?pos=1&code="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>

function recordTrans(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint3").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint3").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","recordtransaction.php?pos=1&code="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And here is my HTML table/form :

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="FinancialDataTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 10%;">Code</th>
                <th style="width: 5%;">Qté</th>
                <th style="width: 25%;">Produit</th>
                <th style="width: 25%;">Description</th>
                <th style="width: 25%;">Prix</th>
                <th style="width: 10%;">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>



              <tr>
                <td>

                    <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="code" name="code" class="form-control" onchange="recordTrans(this.value)"   />
                </div>

                </td>
                <td>

                    <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="qte" id="qte" class="form-control" value="1" onchange="recordTrans(this.value)" />
                </div>

                </td>

                <td colspan="3"><div id="txtHint3" style="width: 100%"> </div></td>



                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="$(this).addClone();">Ajouter un autre article</button></td>
              </tr>

                             </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: I'm sorry the JQuery code has duplicated. the function used is : recordTrans

Comment: *** I need to get and send the values from the textfields id="code" and id="qte"

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="code" name="code" class="form-control" onchange="oncode_change(this.value)"   />
```

```
function oncode_change(str){
   var qteval = $("#qte").val();
   recordTrans(str,qteval )
}

function onqte_change(str){
   var codeval = $("#code").val();
   recordTrans(codeval,str)
}

function recordTrans(codeval, qteval) {
     ...your ajax call here
}
```

Comment: Hi make sense but when trigerring the oncode_change(str) function when #code is onchange, the jquery will not get the other value from the #qte field right?... Since we pass only 1 value as a parameter (str) ..Do I have to change the HTML call to the function? I'm sorry I'm bit new to JQuery and don't know all the code yet

Comment: if you using jquery, you canget a value of any text box like $("#idoftextbox").val(). if you using just javascript you can use document.getElementById("idoftextbox").value. you can get the value of other text value on any other textbox also using the code above

Comment: Hi I see what you have done but for some reason it does not pass the qte value to the PHP

Comment: Your answer is really good I don't understand why the qte value is not passed on to php, I re-posted my sources back. Thank you so much for you help it is really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function oncode_change(str){
    var qteval = $("#qte").val();
    recordTrans(str,qteval )

}

function onqte_change(str){
    var codeval = $("#code").val();
    recordTrans(codeval,str)
}


    function recordTrans(str,qteval) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint3").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint3").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","recordtransaction.php?pos=1&code="+str+"&qte="+qteval,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

}

and HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="FinancialDataTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 10%;">Code</th>
                <th style="width: 5%;">Qté</th>
                <th style="width: 25%;">Produit</th>
                <th style="width: 25%;">Description</th>
                <th style="width: 25%;">Prix</th>
                <th style="width: 10%;">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>



              <tr>
                <td>

                    <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="code" name="code" class="form-control" onchange="oncode_change(this.value)"   />
                </div>

                </td>
                <td>

                    <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="qte" id="qte" class="form-control" value="1" onchange="onqte_change(this.value)" />
                </div>

                </td>

                <td colspan="3"><div id="txtHint3" style="width: 100%"> </div></td>



                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="$(this).addClone();">Ajouter un autre article</button></td>
              </tr>

                             </tbody>
          </table>
```

I really think I did correctly and you answer should normally be working but for some reasean the qte is not passes to the php. Please look : xmlhttp.open("GET","recordtransaction.php?pos=1&code="+str+"&qte="+qteval,true);